# Using a directive to display and populate a select list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've just started using Angularjs and I'm trying to get a list of credit card types displayed in a select list.

I'm getting this error I'm getting (unfortunately stackoverflow wouldn't let me link to it):

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$rootScope/infdig?   p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22addC…22%3A%5C%22SOLO%5C%22%2C%5C%22value%5C%22%3A%5C%22SOL%5C%22%7D%5D%22%5D%5D
at Error (native)
at http://bht.local/Content/app.min.js:11162:450
at h.$digest (http://bht.local/Content/app.min.js:11263:164)
at h.$apply (http://bht.local/Content/app.min.js:11265:287)
at http://bht.local/Content/app.min.js:11174:23
at Object.d [as invoke] (http://bht.local/Content/app.min.js:11190:265)
at $b.c (http://bht.local/Content/app.min.js:11173:439)
at $b (http://bht.local/Content/app.min.js:11174:140)
at Wc (http://bht.local/Content/app.min.js:11173:215)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://bht.local/Content/app.min.js:11365:360) 

app.min.js:11245(anonymous function) app.min.js:11245(anonymous function)     
app.min.js:11222h.$apply app.min.js:11265(anonymous function) app.min.js:11174d 
app.min.js:11190$b.c app.min.js:11173$b app.min.js:11174Wc app.min.js:11173(anonymous function) 
app.min.js:11365fire app.min.js:4414self.fireWith app.min.js:4526jQuery.extend.ready 
app.min.js:1799completed app.min.js:1470

Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22addC…22%3A%5C%22SOLO%5C%22%2C%5C%22value%5C%22%3A%5C%22SOL%5C%22%7D%5D%22%5D%5D
```

What am I doing wrong?  It seems that this code is creating an infinite loop.  I've tried a few things which is what the commented out code is.

Any help/suggestions with this would be sincerely appreciated.

I'm binding it to this html:

```
<div bht-add-credit-card-charge></div>
```

This is my angular directive:

```
.directive('bhtAddCreditCardCharge', function(){
return{
    restrict:'EA',
    scope:true,
    link:function(scope,elem,attrs){

        scope.addCreditCardCharge=function addCreditCardCharge()
        {
            console.log('in addCreditCardCharge')
            scope.creditCards = [
                { name: 'VISA DEBIT/DELTA', value: 'DEL' },
                { name: 'VISA CREDIT', value: 'VIS' },
                { name: 'MASTERCARD CREDIT', value: 'MSC' },
                { name: 'MASTERCARD DEBIT', value: 'MCD' },
                { name: 'MAESTRO', value: 'MAE' },
                { name: 'SWITCH', value: 'SWI' },
                { name: 'VISA ELECTRON', value: 'ELC' },
                { name: 'SOLO', value: 'SOL' }
            ];
            scope.myCreditCard = scope.creditCards[0]; // red

            //return '<select ng-model="myCreditCard" ng-options="creditCard.name for creditCard in creditCards"></select><br>';
            return  scope.creditCards;

        }

    },
    //template: '<select data-ng-bind="addCreditCardCharge()" ng-model="myCreditCard" ng-options="creditCard.name for creditCard in creditCards"></select><br>'
    template: '<span class="creditCards" data-ng-bind="addCreditCardCharge()"></span>'
   }
})
```

Comment: Did you try changing `scope:true,` to `scope: {},`

Comment: Yup, tried that and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this seems to work.

```
 <bht-add-credit-card-charge></bht-add-credit-card-charge>

 .directive('bhtAddCreditCardCharge', function(){
return{
  restrict:'E',
  replace:true,
  link:function(scope,elem,attrs){

   scope.creditCards = [
            { name: 'VISA DEBIT/DELTA', value: 'DEL' },
            { name: 'VISA CREDIT', value: 'VIS' },
            { name: 'MASTERCARD CREDIT', value: 'MSC' },
            { name: 'MASTERCARD DEBIT', value: 'MCD' },
            { name: 'MAESTRO', value: 'MAE' },
            { name: 'SWITCH', value: 'SWI' },
            { name: 'VISA ELECTRON', value: 'ELC' },
            { name: 'SOLO', value: 'SOL' }
        ];

    scope.addCreditCardCharge=function addCreditCardCharge()
    {
        console.log('in addCreditCardCharge')

        scope.myCreditCard = scope.creditCards[0]; // red

        //return '<select ng-model="myCreditCard" ng-options="creditCard.name for
             creditCard in creditCards"></select><br>';
           return  scope.creditCards;

    }

   },
    template: '<div><select  ng-model="myCreditCard" ng-options="creditCard.name for    
                      creditCard in creditCards"></select><br></div>'
   }  
});
```

The main things I did.  The template needs to have a single root element. You had two. I just put the select inside a DIV to illustrate. Changed scope:true to replace:true and made this an element 'E' rather than AE. There are a few other changes you can see as well.